# Will f be a one-one and/or onto function?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a **continuous function** such that $$|f(x) - f(y)| \ge \frac{1}{2}|x-y| for\ all\ x,y \in \Bbb R$$
>   Then will be one-one and/or onto?

The correct answer is at the end of the question. Here's my attempt to to prove it.

I wish to know, if my approach is correct, if there's a shorter more obvious method that I missed out on, because **this is an MCQ question and shouldn't involve such a lengthy processes.**

Assuming $$f(x_1) = f(x_2) for\ some\ x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb R$$

Putting the above values in the given equation we obtain $x_1 = x_2$ Hence our function is easily proven to be **one-one**

For proving onto, I have attempted to use **monotonic** nature of the function(A continuous, one-one function on an interval is onto and $\Bbb R$ is an interval $\implies$ the given function is monotone)

Further, I'd assume that the given function is monotonically increasing(The case where the function is monotonically decreasing follows analogously)

Let $$N \in \Bbb R$$ $$Let\ M>0 \ be \ given$$

If for each $x \in R$ we have $$|f(x) - f(N)| \le M$$ Then putting $x=N+4M$ gives us a contradiction( Since $2M \le M\ is\ never\ true$)

Thus, for each $M \in R, \exists\ x \in R\ such\ that\ x>N\ and$ 
$$|f(x) - f(N)| > M$$
Further, $x>N \implies \ f(x)  \ > \ f(N)\ (Using\ monotonic \ nature\ )$
Thus, we get, for each $M \in R,\ \exists \ x > N\ such\ that\ $ $$f(x) >M+f(N) (Since, \ removing\ mod\ and\ shifting\ f(N)\ to\ RHS)$$

Thus, by applying **Intermediate Value Property constantly** we get $$[f(N),\infty) \subset f(\Bbb R)$$

Similarly, we prove that for each $M>0\ in\  R\ \exists \ some\ x\ < N\ such\ that$ $$f(x)<f(N)-M$$

Then we apply **Intermediate Value Property** constantly to obtain $$(- \infty , f(N)] \subset \Bbb f(R)$$

Thus, $R \subset f(R)$

Correct Answer - f is both one-one and onto
Source - Tata Institute of Fundamental Research, Graduate School Admissions 2014